# Glass material isn't transparent in Eevee

Tags: modeling, eevee-render-engine, glass

I did everything I was told to do,
but it is still completely opaque.

im using blender 3

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Comment: @boots Actually, Alpha Blend will only cause artifacts. Glass in Eevee works just fine in opaque mode :).

Comment: Hi @user138559 :). Are you using a glass BSDF shader or Principled with transmission? That material doesn't even look like glass.

Comment: please add a screenshot of the material's node setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try going into your material tab, scroll down to the alpha settings and ensure the blend mode is not set to opaque. Try Alpha Blend instead.

[image: Find it here]

Comment: Hi :). Glass in Eevee works just fine in opaque mode. You use the Refraction options to control it :)